# Using a partial template class as a specialized template function

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, template-specialization, specialization

I have a template, and I want to specialize it using a vector (which is a template itself). It is possible?

Here is the compiler error:
error C2768: 'serialize' : illegal use of explicit template arguments.

A little example of what I need to do:

```
template<typename T>
void serialize(T data, Stream& stream)
{
    //...
}

template<typename MT>
void serialize<map<string, MT>>(map<string, MT> data, Stream& stream)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I can't specialize my template function with a partial templated class?

Comment: I take that back. You can't do partial specialization of function templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no partial specialization of function templates.

There is only full specialization (which is usually a bad idea), and overloading.

```
template<typename MT>
void serialize(map<string, MT> data, Stream& stream)
{
  //...
}
```

would be an overload.  If you always allowed type deduction to happen, it would probably behave like you would expect specialization to work.

Stick any `std` namespace stuff you want to support in the namespace of `serialize`.  Stick other `serialize` overloads in the namespace of the class you want to change the behavior of.

---

If you really, really need partial specialization, forward your work into a template class, and do partial specialization of that class.

```
template<class T>
struct serialize_impl {
  void operator()(T data, Stream& stream) const {
    // ...
  }
};
template<class MT>
struct serialize_impl<map<string, MT>> {
  void operator()(map<string MT> data, Stream& stream) const {
    // ...
  }
};
```

then

```
template<class T>
void serialize(T data, Stream& stream) {
  serialize_impl<T>{}(data, stream);
}
```

however this is often a bad idea, and overloading is usually the right thing to do.

Also, don't take things by value when serializing.  Take then by `T const&`.